# Can't NOT Escape html in Laravel 4 Blade Template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have this simple blade template

```
 @foreach ($records as $record)
    <tr>
      @foreach ($column_names as $column_name)
        <td>
          {{{ucwords($record[$column_name]) }}}
        </td>
      @endforeach
     </tr>
 @endforeach
```

that parses an array, I am injecting html hyperlink code into some of my records, But I can't get it to **NOT** escape the html.

and Yes i've tried using the Double curly's `{{ }}` but it prints out the entire part including the curly's

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Can you add your view result?

Comment: This is what I get with double curlys, http://i.imgur.com/3rSggbt.png

Comment: Do you already save your view with `.blade.php` ?

Comment: yes it's called showtable.blade.php, i'm using it more than once

Comment: Have you tried using {!! !!} instead? The new Laravel versions do not use the {{ }} by default.

Comment: Mmmm... try `{{ ucwords($record[$column_name]) }}`? Notice the space between the braces

Comment: I use Version 4.2, {!! !!} doesn't register, I tried it anyway

Comment: I tried the Spaces, it didn't work, same thing I posted

Comment: In your config folder, do you have a line like this: 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' under providers? in the app.php

Comment: You should try on a blank new Laravel 4 install and see if you have the problem. You've changed something in your code somewhere thats broken the blade template system - and we are not going to be able to work it out from the code you've posted so far

Comment: I have that line in my config under app.php

Comment: ok, give me some time